# AWS java/android SDK on SQS: QueueDoesNotExistException

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to delete a message on SQS but with no success. I get a QueueDoesNotExistException even though I just fetched the messages from the url/queue. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is the function I wrote:

```
public ArrayList<String> receiveSqsMessages(String url) {
    AmazonSQSClient client = getSQSClient(Regions.SA_EAST_1);

    ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest(url);
    request.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    request.setWaitTimeSeconds(5);

    ArrayList<Message> messageList = null;

    try {
        ReceiveMessageResult result = client.receiveMessage(request);
        messageList = new ArrayList<Message>(result.getMessages());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ac) {
        return null;
    }

    ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Message m : messageList) {
        String current_message = m.getBody();

        if(md5(current_message).equals(m.getMD5OfBody())) {
            messages.add(current_message);
            String ticket = m.getReceiptHandle();

            DeleteMessageRequest delete = new DeleteMessageRequest();
            delete.setReceiptHandle(ticket);
            client.deleteMessage(delete);
        }
    }
    return messages;
}

private AmazonSQSClient getSQSClient(Regions regions) {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_KEY);

    Region region = Region.getRegion(regions);

    AmazonSQSClient client = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials);
    client.setRegion(region);

    return client;
}
```

I confirmed the messages are being retrieved using Log.d in the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting `queueUrl` to `DeleteMessageRequest`. You should call `setQueueUrl(String queueUrl)` on your `DeleteMessageRequest` object. You can read more about it on [DeleteMessageRequest Javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/DeleteMessageRequest.html).